# Problems with WPF Demo Zxing 'BarcodeWriter' does not exist

Tags: .net, wpf, zxing

When i try to run the project i get the error: The type or namespace name 'BarcodeWriter' does not exist in the namespace 'ZXing.Presentation' (are you missing an assembly reference?) and The type or namespace name 'BarcodeWriterGeometry' does not exist in the namespace 'ZXing.Presentation' (are you missing an assembly reference?) i did install the NuGet Package but i see that under zxing.presentation on References there is only 1 class > BarcodeReader
i dont see the BarcodeWriter class.

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed the current source of the demo from the repository with the assemblies of the latest released version. The source in the repository is newer and uses some classes which are available with the next version of ZXing.Net.

Please use the complete source from the repository (library and demo) or use the sources of the demo from the download section at codeplex.
https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/releases/

Comment: thanks for the tip. i was able to execute the Demo. What are the requirements for the format of the image i need to use png,jpg,size,quality, etc

Comment: Quality: as good as possible. Format: everything which is supported by the class BitmapImage.